# PS4 - disc and digital copy of the same game

Tags: ps4, psn, detroit-become-human

I have a copy of Detroit: Become Human on disc and I have the digital deluxe edition, which was bought through the store. I had already played the disc version before buying the digital version.

Since I have the disc version already: do I only have the bonus content or do I actually have the digital version too? Is it just because I have that version installed that I still have to use the disc to play?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have had this happen multiple times, especially with free PS+ games. I've always had to uninstall the disc version then download the digital version. You can back up your saved games if you're concerned about losing them, but they should be fine.

The disc version probably doesn't install literally everything since it can read some content from the disc, so it makes sense that you'd need to install a new version to play it without the disc.

Answer (score 4):

If you buy a digital version of a game you already had on disc, it removes the requirement that you have the disc in the system to play. You would now own the digital version of the full game plus whatever bonus content came with the digital purchase.

Comment: Actually, for me, I bought Trackmania on disc and a few months later, it came out on PS plus for free, but I click to start and it still says insert the disc.

Comment: @GoneBoyGone Did you actually specifically get the PS+ free version? I did the exact same with Until Dawn and it worked fine for me.

Comment: So if I delete the version that requires me to use the disc, I can just install the digital version?

Comment: You shouldn't need to delete it, when you click on download through the store, PSN should detect that you don't have the digital copy and simply download the digital version, overwriting the disc required one. Should use the same saves and trophies.

Comment: That is strange, @pboss3010, it never did that for me. I still have to use the disc to play.

Comment: @devianttea: I'm not sure why Sony made it this way, but you have to delete the disc version and download the digital version. I've done this with both Destiny games and a few others. Until you delete the disc version (even though both games are the same), it will require the disc to be inserted. I think of it like the disc containing a license to play the game that isn't inherent in the installation. The downloaded version has this license inherent in the installation (this probably isn't totally accurate, but it definitely provides a basis for how the installations work.)

Comment: Interesting, I'm pretty sure I didn't have any issues with MGS5, but it's been awhile since I played it.